# OpenSUSE Leap 15.0 boots directly to TTY1 (no X)

Tags: linux, partitioning, libreoffice, opensuse

I am pretty sure I'll have to reinstall everything from scratch, but figured I should create a post here just in case someone has a great idea. Back story of how I got here is at bottom of post. tl;dr version of that story is that LibreOffice appears to have corrupted my HDD.

The pathology:

- I now have a computer that boots up, tries to start, then goes to TTY1. When I try the TTY7, there's a flashing dash and no GUI. At the top of the TTY1 is an error message that is very similar to the OP's original post in this thread (particularly the ACPI errors):
  https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=251998
- Whenever I try sudo I get

  `sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/ts/rajan: No space left on device`
- df -m shows that there is plenty of space on all partitions, including the partition (/dev/sda2, which has 9 GB free) that holds /var, /tmp, /opt, /root, and lots of other important directories.
- `systemctl get-default` (I *think* I used `sudo` for that) gives `graphical.target`
- `systemctl status display-manager` gives a lot of issues, I'm trying to get that text over to the computer I'm using right now to post.
- startx throws errors that it couldn't create lock file in `/tmp/.tX0-lock`, connection is refused, and some other errors.
- `/usr/` is one of the /dev/sda2 partitions, and I can go to a directory and delete a large file (I just deleted the README from Google Cloud's SDK which was 382KB) and I still can't `touch` a file in that same directory because `No space left on device`

Quite irritating and I am pretty sure I lost all my data, but if anyone has ideas I'm all up for trying things. Particularly if there's a way for me to extract the data off the computer first.

Origin story of this debacle - I tried to create a presentation with LibreOffice Impress and embedded OLE objects (files) into the presentation to transfer collateral files to a coworker. This created some catastrophic issues with the disk when I tried to save the file (got some sort of permissions error) and LibreOffice crashed hard. After that I started to have these issues described above.

One more thread coming to troubleshoot my inability to get FTP working in my intranet that I'm trying to use to salvage some of the data....

Comment: I was able to use `sudo fdisk -l` to find the /dev folder for a USB/external drive I plugged in, mounted in the ~/ directory and retrieved files I hadn't backed up yet. Going to wipe and start all over again if nobody has more input. Although I might try a pretty aggressive disk repair attempt just to see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Appears this was a corrupted partition. The partition `/dev/sda2` was corrupted, and after reformatting the HDD I have no further issues. I think Libreoffice wrote some tmp files into that partition (it hosted /tmp, and other partitions), and when Libreoffice crashed it made the partition unusable.

One solution I could have taken is to create a new Open Suse OS partition, and then I could have backed everything up. I chose to do a clean wipe of the HDD and eliminate all traces of previous OS.

One important comment is that I still get the APCI errors from the first bullet point, so I think they're just the OS being over-cautious, as one of the answers in the linuxmint thread suggests.